# Ways to check if your phone has been compromised?

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, malware

With more and more people using custom ROMs and APKs from unknown sources (some with root access) it's inevitable that Android phones are getting compromised.

What are some methods that can be used to see if your phone is compromised.

Examples I've thought of so far include:

1. monitor outgoing traffic (is there an app for this?)
2. List on going processes (how can I see processes that aren't in the app tray?)

Comment: Define *compromised* here? Data leak and violation of privacy kind of happens all the time and users do that by giving permissions during installation time, so I don't assume that would count into compromised here.

Comment: Not a simple data leak. More like remote root access. Any type of malware that can't be removed by simply uninstalling a single app.

Answer (score 1):

Power off your phone.
Power on your phone. Note the Google logo. 
Is an unlocked padlock symbol underneath your Google logo?
That symbol means you have an unlocked bootloader, which opens your phone up to bigger compromises.

Comment: That's not much useful, really. If the bootloader had been unlocked without user's knowledge then the data would have been [automatically] wiped as well, in turn, triggering to user that device had been tampered with or was used without authorization.

Comment: Obviously I wasn't referring to someone unlocking the bootloader.     Forgetting to re-lock the bootloader opens the device up to all sorts of potential attacks. As you pointed out, with a locked bootloader you know that nothing has been flashed, as that would automatically wipe the device.   An unlocked bootloader,  technically speaking is the definition of compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

[Network Monitoring: How to Get Started and Why You Should Consider it](http://www.xda-developers.com/network-monitoring-how-to-get-started-and-why-you-should-consider-it/), a post which appeared on XDA portal  explains this using [Fiddler- The free web debugging proxy for any browser, system or platform](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

The XDA post explains, set up of Fiddler, creating a proxy, connecting your phone and laptop on the same WiFi network and analysing traffic.